# Virtualized Broadband Adapter Windows 10 (Experts)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, mikrotik-routeros, mobile-broadband

everyone. After looking through all internet, I can´t solve my problem with a interface Broadband Adapter LTE (SIM) and one router virtualized.

I need connect the virtual machine with Mikrotik on Windows 10 with the Adapter whatever. NAT is not a solution.

I´m using Windows 10 PRO and virtualbox to running a router Mikrotik, this router is going to create a VPN eoIP with other Mikrotik equipment through internet.
[Pic of the Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT0co.png)

With Virtualbox and PCI interfaces don´t have any problems to connect the VPN(Wired and Wirless), but the broadband interface don´t appear at interface list of Virtualbox network adapter.

I´m had reading about this problem, and the virtual machines don´t support this type of adapters, only PCI adapters are recognised by virtual machines. Is this true? Don´t have support any software of virtualized?

Second, I have tried joined the Broadband interface with a Hyper-V Vitual Ethernet Adapter with ICS and this interface configured with virtualbox, but the router need to see the internet IP or the other equipment to make the VPN. And with this configuration don´t happen.

Also, I have tried use this interface as usb interface at virtual machine, but the Mikrotik software don´t support this.

After this I have several questions:

- Are there any software of virtual machines that support usb adapters as network interfaces?

*Are there any way to join the broadband interface and the virtual interface without ICS? I need the broadband IP´s and connetivity.

*Any other ideas about solve this configuration?

Best Regards

Comment: What kind of network is a "broadband adapter", exactly? Is it LTE? ADSL? DOCSIS? 10BROAD36? (Either way, not Ethernet, I'm going to assume.)

Comment: LTE Network, edited.

Answer (score 0):

In bridge mode, the VM manager emulates a virtual **Ethernet** network interface, then copies Ethernet frames between the guest and a physical interface. (The guest doesn't know anything about the physical one.)

Doing this requires the physical interface to be Ethernet-compatible at layer-2 – e.g. LTE "wwan" or "ppp" interfaces do not use the Ethernet frame format, so they cannot be bridged with Ethernet, while Wi-Fi interfaces can (kind of).

This requirement depends entirely on the network type, and has nothing to do with how the interface is attached. For example, if you tried to use a USB Ethernet adapter, it *could* be bridged with the VM's virtual Ethernet – but a PCI FireWire adapter or a PCI Infiniband adapter still could not.

So if you have an LTE interface, you cannot attach it to a virtual Ethernet interface *because it is LTE and not Ethernet.*

Your alternatives:

1. It sounds like you have a USB network adapter, so use USB passthrough.

   In this mode, VirtualBox disconnects the physical interface from the host OS and directly connects it to the guest, at PCI or USB level instead of network frame level.

   This works with any type of network interface (or indeed any PCI/USB device in general), but requires VirtualBox to support "PCI passthrough" or "USB passthrough", and the *guest OS* needs the correct drivers for that device.
2. Use NAT, but encapsulate EoIP inside an UDP-based tunnel.

   ICS NAT actually should be able to handle GRE (EoIP), whereas VirtualBox NAT might not. However, all of them will handle UDP just fine.

   To do this, set up IPsec (IKEv2) between both EoIP endpoints and create an ESP or AH policy for the GRE protocol. When IKEv2 detects NAT, it will automatically enable UDP encapsulation.

   This will reduce your MTU somewhat (UDP + ESP + cipher overhead), so if you started with 1500 you'll end up with 1438 or even 1414 bytes maximum.

Comment: I answer in a new answer by the size

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the ethernet frames/LTE frames concept.
The MikrotiK OS don´t support USB devices. So the USB is discarded.
The problem that I have saw is how make the UDP tunnel with IKEv2-EoIP without direct visibility of the IP from each side.

Comment: At physical router I will haven´t problems because it has a public IP at router Mitrokit interface, but with the Mitrokit OS located at virtual machine I can´t see how route the tunnel "A" IP address ( against the Mikrotik SW router). Because the frames have to pass through "LTE adapter and the Interface virtualized with ICS".

Comment: I think that I need a NAT system in addition that ICS of windows, right? What IP should use at physical router in order to come to the Mikrotik router? IP public of LTE adapter, and NATting?